# Value from new window, button, and script to main script/window python+tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button

I have a main script. When you push the button (in tkinter) you open a class with a new window and a new button.
When you click the new button (in the new window and different file) the text in the main window should be updated.

I have the following:

Main script

```
from tkinter import *
from kandit import Kandit

root=Tk()

def hoop():
    s=Kandit()
    label.configure(text=s)

button=Button(root, text="ok", command=hoop)
button.grid(row=0,column=0)

label=Label(root, text="nog niet dus")
label.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Sub-script

```
class Kandit:
  def __init__(self):
  self.Master=Toplevel()
  self.Button=Button(self.Master, text="check", command=self.Return())
  self.Button.grid(row=0,column=0)
  self.Master.mainloop()
def Return(self):
  self.Keuze="nothing"
  return self.Keuze #, self.Master.destroy()
```

except from the destroy it works until the moment I press the "check" button.
Than nothing happens.

Comment: First of all you wrote `self.Button = Button(..., command=self.Return())`, I think you wanted to write `self.Button = Button(..., command=self.Return)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk


class Kandit:
    def __init__(self):
        # Set the default value for keuze:
        self.keuze = None
        self.master = tk.Toplevel()
        # If the user presses the "X" in the window toolbar call `_return`
        self.master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.destroy)
        # When the button is pressed call `_return`
        self.button = tk.Button(self.master, text="check", command=self._return)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0)
        # Start the mainloop. Later we will stop the mainloop
        # Note it waits until the button is pressed/window closed
        self.master.mainloop()
        # Here we can garantee that `_return` was called
        # and `self.keuze` has set to the value we need.

    def _return(self):
        # Set the result in a variable
        self.keuze = "nothing"
        self.destroy()

    def destroy(self):
        # Stop the mainloop so that the program can continue
        self.master.quit()
        # Remove the window from the screen
        self.master.destroy()


def hoop():
    # Create the window and wait until the button is pressed/window closed
    new_window = Kandit()
    # Get the result from the class
    new_text = new_window.keuze
    #if 
    # Set the label with the result
    label.configure(text=new_text)


root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text="ok", command=hoop)
button.grid(row=0, column=0)

label = tk.Label(root, text="nog niet dus")
label.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

The problem in your case is that you can't return values from the `__init__` method. This is why you have you save the result to a variable and retrieve it later

Comment: It does not work if the second window is closed by clicking the close button in the title bar.

Comment: @acw1668 thx for that I changed my answer

Comment: You change still do not update the label in main window after closing the second window using the title bar close button.  You need to use `self.master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self._return)` instead.

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. Thnx TheLizzard, as for the solution as for the explanation why it didn't work at the first place.
And i'm also learning from you notation method. 
Thanks again

Comment: @acw1668 I thought that destroying the window will stop that `mainloop` (my bad should have tested it). I didn't want to make it too complicated but I guess I will have to change that protocol. I think that happened because OP used `Toplevel` and I usually use `Tk`.

Comment: @TobiasS I added comments explaining how it works. Tell me if you still don't get it. Btw I am not the best teacher :D.

Comment: @TheLizzard i'm almost getting it.
The question left is: is it ok to do just this: self.master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW")
without the self._return.  Because when the "user" clicks "X" i simply want that nothing happends

Comment: @TobiasS I edited my answer (just had to comment out that line).

Comment: @TheLizzard when i tried that solution i could not close the window by pressing "X", so i just left out the self._return. I will try it again

Comment: @TobiasS I made a stupid mistake :D. Can you please try it again

Comment: @TobiasS if this is the answer you were looking for consider accepting my answer so that other people don't waste time answering the question as well